# Regular expression for a decimal with a max of 2 digits before decimal point

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regular expression that works for a decimal with a max of 2 digits before the decimal point and 2 digits after the decimal point.  The decimal point and decimal places are optional.  So these values would be accepted :

```
90
5.4
45.21
0.5
0
```

And the would be  rejected :

```
100
105.56
05.6
55.543
78.
```

Can any regex gurus help?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why would `05.6` and `78.` be rejected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
^[1-9]\d?(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

If you want to accept even `0.5`, try this:

```
^(?:[1-9]\d?|0)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Comment: Excellent, works like a charm.  Out of interest, how would I amend this to only accept 1 digit before the decimal point rather than 2? Would I remove the first (?:) ?

Comment: Your second `(?:)` is redundant. `|` takes as wide a scope as possible.

Comment: @user517406: You can replace the first `(?:..)` with `\d`: The regex is then: `^\d(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you

```
\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\A[1-9]?\d(?:\.\d{1,2})?\z/
```

..................